# How can I get the positions for which my agent should move next?

Tags: c

I am a beginner working on a prey-predator simulation in C and I need to decide the position to where each of my agents will move next based on a criterion. Only up, right, down and left are allowed (no diagonals). The candidate/possible cells should be numbered starting at 0 in clockwise order (so it should be up->right->down->left). Each of these cells is a possible candidate if they are empty.

```
typedef enum Neighbor {
    up, right, down, left
} Neighbor;
```

Heres my cell structure and initialisation:

```
typedef struct Cell {
    int x, y;
    int empty;
    Neighbor *neighbor;
    Agent *agent;
} Cell;

Cell *initCell(int x, int y) {
    Cell *cell = calloc(1, sizeof(Cell));
    cell->x = x;
    cell->y = y;
    cell->empty = 0;
    cell->agent = NULL;
    return cell;
}
```

I have an auxiliary function that gets all the possible cells and chooses the one the agent will move to according to the following criterion: (ngen+x+y)%count. The function returns the chosen cell.

```
Cell *getAdjacentEmpty(Field *field, int ngen, int x, int y) {
    int dx, dy;
    int count = 0; 
    Cell *candidates[4]; 
    
    for (Neighbor n = up; n <= left; n++) {
        switch (n)
        {
            case up:
                dx = 0; dy = -1;
                break;
            case right:
                dx = 1; dy = 0;
                break;
            case down:
                dx = 0; dy = 1;
                break;
            case left:
                dx = -1; dy = 0;
                break;
        }
        Cell *candidate = position(field, x+dx, y+dy);
        if (candidate->agent == NULL && candidate->agent->species != ROCK) {
            if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x <= field->rows-1 && y <= field->cols-1) {
                candidates[count] = candidate;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
        return NULL;
    return candidates[(ngen+x+y)%count];
```

I call this function from another function to update my field at each iteration.

```
void updateField(Field *field, int ngen, int rproc, int fproc, int fhunger, int move) {
    int i,j;
    int rows = field->rows;
    int cols = field->cols;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            Cell *cell = position(field, i, j);
            Agent *agent = cell->agent;
            Cell *nextcell = getAdjacentEmpty(field, ngen, agent->x, agent->y);
            nextcell->agent = agent;
            agent->x = nextcell->x;
            agent->y = nextcell->y;
            (...)
        }
     }
}
```

When I try to run it, I get this error: "error: expected expression
Cell *nextcell = getAdjacentEmpty(field, ngen, agent..."

Basically, I am not able to get the coordinates to move to when I call the getAdjacentEmpty function from the updateField and I am completely stuck.

How can I do this from the updateField function?
I appreciate any help. If I am doing anything else that doesn't make sense, please, feel free to point it out.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Aside I think you should check that `x+dx` and `y+dy` are not off-field *before* dereferencing a pointer computed from their values. Also, I would used an array of `dx`, `dy`, offsets instead of going through `switch` cases.

Comment: Did you try separating the definition and the first writing of non-initialisation? E.g. `Cell *nextcell;  nextcell= getAdjacentEmpty(field, ngen, agent->x, agent->y);`